# Variablize Method Call in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to dynamically call a method or property of a function. For example say I wanted to call every property of $Error[0]. I could get a list of all the property names with:

```
$a = ($error[0] | get-member -type property | select Name)
```

I would then like to do something like this:

```
foreach($b in $a){
     $error[0].&($b.Name)
}
```

But the call operator (&) doesn't resolve $b.Name like I would expect (it should resolve to 'CatagoryInfo'). Is there anyway to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use different way to retrieve properties:

```
$Properties=$Error[0].PSObject.Properties
```

This will return collection of `PSPropertyInfo` objects. `PSPropertyInfo` objects have `Value` property which you could use to get or set property value:

```
$Properties|ForEach-Object {'Name={0}; Value={1}'-f$_.Name,$_.Value}
```

Also note of some possible problems in your way of retrieving properties' values. PowerShell allows you to access `IDictionary` elements with property syntax. Problem here is that PowerShell prefer to access to a collection element rather than actual property:

```
$Hashtable=@{}
$Hashtable.Count
# 0
$Hashtable.Add('SomeName',10)
$Hashtable.SomeName
# 10
$Hashtable.Count
# 1
$Hashtable.Add('Count',20)
$Hashtable.Count
# 20
$Hashtable|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Invoke-Expression`:

```psh
$a = ($error[0] | get-member -type property | select Name)

foreach($b in $a){
     Invoke-Expression "`$error[0].$($b.Name)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the &

```
$a = ($error[0] | get-member -type property | select Name)

foreach($b in $a){
     $error[0].($b.Name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I was overthinking it.